# Custom implementation of "tail -f" functionality in C

Tags: python, c

**EDIT:** I used, finally, inotify. As stefanB says, inotify is the thing to use. I found a tail clone that uses inotify to implement the -f mode, [inotail](http://distanz.ch/inotail/).

Original question text:

I'm trying to implement the "tail -f" logic in a C project, for prototyping purposes I developed it in python as follow:

```
    # A forever loop, each 5 seconds writes a line into file.txt
    from time import *

    while 1:
        sleep(5)
        file = open("file.txt", "a")
        file.write("This is a test\n")
        file.close()
```

The next code follows the eof of file.txt (updated by the code above)

```
    # tail -f 
    from time import *

    file = open("file.txt", "r")
    file.seek(0, 2)

    while 1:
      line = file.readline()
      if not line:
          sleep(1)
      else:
          print line

    file.close()
```

All works fine but the C implementation is not working (there are no check-error code). The inclusion of stdio.h, string.h and unistd.h is omitted (the colorization hides the header inclusion code).

```
    #define LINE_LEN 256

    int main(int argc, char **argv)
    {
        FILE *f;
        char line[LINE_LEN];

        f = fopen("file.txt", "r");

        fseek(f, 0, SEEK_END);

        while (1)
        {
            fgets(line, LINE_LEN, f);

            if (strlen(line) == 0)
            {
                sleep(1);
            }
            else
            {
                printf("Readed: %s", line);
            } 
        }

        fclose(f);

        return 0;
    }
```

Some idea?

Is a good idea implement it with a poll() instead the presented solution?.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**EDIT**:
Seems like [inotify](http://www.linuxjournal.com/article/8478) is the thing to use. It should be included in linux kernel since 2.6.13 . [An article from IBM developerworks about inotify](http://www.ibm.com/developerworks/linux/library/l-ubuntu-inotify/index.html?ca=drs-).

Previous answer:

Have a look at Linux [File Alteration Monitor](http://oss.sgi.com/projects/fam/faq.html) (in linux kernels 2.4.x >). It's a framework that let's you subscribe for file changes and you get callback from kernel when change happens. This should be better than polling.

[Examples](http://techpubs.sgi.com/library/tpl/cgi-bin/getdoc.cgi?coll=0650&db=bks&fname=/SGI_Developer/books/IIDsktp_IG/sgi_html/ch08.html) how to poll for file changes, check out sections **Waiting for file changes** and **Polling for file changes**.

I haven't tried it yet.

Answer (score 3):

Once a FILE * has seen an error or eof, it has its internal status set so that it continues to return error or eof on subsequent calls.  You need to call `clearerr(f);` after the sleep returns to clear the eof setting and get it to try to read more data from the file.

Answer (score 2):

From the `tail` [man page](http://www.monkey.org/cgi-bin/man2html?tail):

> -f    Do not stop when end-of-file is reached, but rather to wait for
>   additional data to be appended to the
>   input. If the file is replaced (i.e.,
>   the inode number changes), tail will
>   reopen the file and continue. If the
>   file is truncated, tail will reset its
>   position to the beginning. This makes
>   tail more useful for watching log
>   files that may get rotated. The -f
>   option is ignored if the standard
>   input is a pipe, but not if it is a
>   FIFO.

So, you could do the same thing:

1. Use [stat()](http://linux.die.net/man/2/stat) to read the inode number of the file
2. Display the contents of that file. Store the position of the file descriptor eg, p = ftell(fd)
3. Use stat() again, and see if the inode has changed. If so, display the contents of the file from position p onward
4. Repeat