# How could I incrementally display JSON data but not repeatedly parse and display in WEB

Tags: javascript, json, perl, web

I have a log file, which is logged by a real-time running script, now I am going to monitor the status of the script from the log at WEB/HTML, so I use JavaScript to update the WEB/HTML, also I write one CGI script to parse the log and output event status to JSON for JavaScript's reading. The JS script periodically(every 2 second for example) invoke the CGI to parse the log and invoke getJSON to read event status, then update the WEB.

eg. at time T(second), the log file logged:

event 1 start ...

doing event 1 ...

event 1 pass  ...

event 1 end   ...

at time T+2(second), the log file logged:

event 1 start ...

doing event 1 ...

event 1 pass  ...

event 1 end   ...

event 2 start ...

doing event 2 ...

event 2 fail  ...

event 2 end   ...

the CGI at time T(second) may output:

{"event":[["event 1", "pass"]]}

at some URI, which will be read by JS's getJSON

and at time T+2(second) may output:

{"event":[["event 1", "pass"],["event 2", "failed"]]}

---

So here, the CGI script I implemented will parse the whole log every 2 second, which may consume lot of system resource when the log is large and do repeated things for the event that already done.

Anyone have a idea how could I parse the log incrementally by output and not whole log, and how to store the already done event's status?

Comment: What are you using for CGI ? On which OS ?

Comment: CGI parse the log and output event status to JSON. RHEL system.

Comment: I mean, what technology are you using to write your CGI script ?

Comment: Why don't you pass the last event id to your CGI script, and return only events generated after that id?

Comment: @bfavaretto, who pass the last event id to CGI?

Comment: You said the JS script invokes the CGI, so you could pass it from there, as a GET parameter.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you don't want to parse the entire log file every time, you should try to mimic the behavior of [tail -f](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/883784/custom-implementation-of-tail-f-functionality-in-c):

- Open the log and parse everything (the first time).
- Fetch the cursor position with [getpos](http://perldoc.perl.org/IO/Seekable.html).
- Fetch the [inode](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Inode) number and `mtime` with [stat](http://perldoc.perl.org/functions/stat.html).
- Save with the cursor and the inode in a separate file.

When the next call arrives, compare the inode number with the one you saved:

- If it has changed, then the file was modified (like after a logrotate). You need to start reading from the beginning.
- If the `mtime` has changed, seek to the old position with `setpos` and resume parsing.
- Otherwise, nothing has changed.

With this solution, you'll be able to parse the file chunk by chunk. Be careful, you might sometimes have an edge case when only a part of a line has been written.

**EDIT**: @mob's comment

Comment: Why would appending to a file change the inode? It is better to compare the sizes of the file.

Comment: you're right, the inode changes when the whole file is modified, usually after a logrotate. I'll edit my answer.